# Converting one Func delegate to another for use with a generic repository

Tags: nhibernate, lambda, repository-pattern, func

My aim is to achieve something like this:

```
IList<People> peeps = _peopleRepository.Get<People>(x.Name == "dan");   
//signature looks like this:  IList<T> Get<T>(Func<T, bool> query) where T : IEntity;
```

This would be doing this internally:

```
_sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().QueryOver<People>(x.Name=="dan").List();
//NHibernate.IQueryOver<T,T> QueryOver<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T>> alias)
where T : class
```

This issue I have is converting my 'query' to the 'alias' as the types are obviously different. Is this a futile task? Is there away of achieving what I am aiming for?

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't use NHibernate, it seems as though your type signatures are different.  Your Get method should be accepting a parameter of type `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>>`.  This way you can pass it to the QueryOver method which accepts a parameter of the same type.